# Nginx proxy forward and preserve original links?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

Here is my current config:

```
server {
    location ~ ^/bugsbunny/?(.*)$ {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_pass       http://127.0.0.2:8080/cartoon/network/$1;
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure out how to reverse-proxy requests and preserve the original host. For example let's say I have `http://127.0.0.1/bugsbunny` as my front-end and I want to reverse-proxy the requests to `http://127.0.0.2:8080/cartoon/network`. How to preserve the original url so that `http://127.0.0.2:8080/cartoon/network/something/other` would become `http://127.0.0.1/bugsbunny/something/other` on the front-end ?

P.S. I tried using `proxy_set_header Host $host;` but this preserves only the original host.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found it myself. 
You have to rewrite the links yourself via [HttpSubModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpSubModule#sub_filter_once). Be sure to set `sub_filter_once off` so that it replaces all the links on the page, not just the first one it finds.